# Create archive from difference of two folders

Tags: bash, diff

I have the following problem.
There are two nested folders A and B. They are mostly identical, but B has a few files that A does not. (These are two mounted rootfs images).
I want to create a shell script that does the following:

1. Find out which files are contained in B but not in A.
2. copy the files found in 1. from B and create a tar.gz that contains these files, keeping the folder structure.

The goal is to import the additional data from image B afterwards on an embedded system that contains the contents of image A.

For the first step I put together the following code snippet. Note to grep "Nur" : "Nur in" = "Only in" (german):

```
diff -rq <A> <B>/ 2>/dev/null | grep Nur | awk '{print substr($3, 1, length($3)-1) "/" substr($4, 1, length($4)-1)}'
```

The result is the output of the paths relative to folder B.

I have no idea how to implement the second step. Can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `diff` for finding files which don't exist is severe overkill; you are doing a lot of calculations to compare the contents of the files, where clearly all you care about is whether a file name exists or not.

Maybe try this instead.

```
tar zcf newfiles.tar.gz $(comm -13 <(cd A && find . -type f | sort) <(cd B && find . -type f | sort) | sed 's/^\./B/')
```

The `find` commands produce a listing of the file name hierarchies; `comm -13` extracts the elements which are unique to the second input file (which here isn't really a file at all; we are using the shell's process substitution facility to provide the input) and the `sed` command adds the path into B back to the beginning.

Passing a command substitution `$(...)` as the argument to `tar` is problematic; if there are a lot of file names, you will run into "command line too long", and if your file names contain whitespace or other irregularities in them, the shell will mess them up. The standard solution is to use `xargs` but using `xargs tar cf` will overwrite the output file if `xargs` ends up calling `tar` more than once; though perhaps your `tar` has an option to read the file names from standard input.

Comment: Use the option `-T` and put `comm` in a process substitution: `tar ... -T <(comm ...)`

Comment: @ceving It's unclear which platform you are talking about; my `tar` does not have this option. (I'm guessing you are on Linux.)

Comment: I would say: GNU tar belongs to GNU bash. (The question is tagged with [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash).)

Comment: Bash exists on many, many platforms where the userland utilities are not the GNU ones. Ignoring matters of portability just makes answers worse and harder to reuse.

Comment: It seems like this solution does also list many files that exist in both directories.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I missed the `sort`! Sorry for the hassle, can you try again?

Comment: The first part works now, but tar fails:

`tar (child): newfiles.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory`

Comment: Silly typo, dunno why I had `t` instead of `c`

Answer (score 2):

With `find`:

```sh
$ mkdir -p A B
$ touch A/a A/b
$ touch B/a B/b B/c B/d
$ cd B
$ find . -type f -exec sh -c '[ ! -f ../A/"$1" ]' _ {} \; -print
./c
./d
```

The idea is to use the `exec` action with a shell script that tests the existence of the current file in the other directory. There are a few subtleties:

- The first argument of `sh -c` is the script to execute, the second (here `_` but could be anything else) corresponds to the `$0` positional parameter of the script and the third (`{}`) is the current file name as set by `find` and passed to the script as positional parameter `$1`.
- The `-print` action at the end is needed, even if it is normally the default with `find`, because the use of `-exec` cancels this default.

Example of use to generate your tarball with GNU `tar`:

```sh
$ cd B
$ find . -type f -exec sh -c '[ ! -f ../A/"$1" ]' _ {} \; -print > ../list.txt
$ tar -c -v -f ../diff.tar --files-from=../list.txt
./c
./d
```

Note: if you have unusual file names the `--verbatim-files-from` GNU `tar` option can help. Or a combination of the `-print0` action of `find` and the `--null` option of GNU `tar`.

Note: if the shell is POSIX (e.g., `bash`) you can also run `find` from the parent directory and get the path of the files relative from there, if you prefer:

```sh
$ mkdir -p A B
$ touch A/a A/b
$ touch B/a B/b B/c B/d
$ find B -type f -exec sh -c '[ ! -f A"${1#B}" ]' _ {} \; -print
B/c
B/d
```

Comment: You could the `test` binary: `find . -type f -not -exec test -e '../A/{}' \; -print`

Comment: Yes, this would also work. I like the shell script idea because it allows more sophisticated processing (like the parameter expansion in the second example) but you're right, in the first example we can simplify a bit.